# Splitting a file into multiple files

Tags: c#, split

I have a text file which has

```
DXS....
1Line
2Line
DXE
DXS
1Line
2Line
DXS
```

I need code to read the above file and write into the another file till it sees the `DXE`. So basically I will have multiple files which will consist of lines from `DXS` till `DXE`.
In the above case I will have 2 files created.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a "please write my code for me" site; for that, you should try somewhere like [Rentacoder](http://www.rentacoder.com). If you edit your post and provide what you've tried so far and explain what didn't work as expected, someone here will be glad to try and help you. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good introduction to learn how to [read and write text files in C#](http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/ReadWriteTextFile.aspx). I would also take a look at [File.ReadAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx) or [File.ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx) and their counterparts [File.WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx) and [File.WriteAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383693.aspx).

If you already have code and it's simply not working right, edit your question to include it and we can help you iron out the kinks.